# UI Testing with Fragment after replace

Tags: android, testing, fragment

I have a App with several Fragments which are managed by one Activity. My Problem is that I want to test the Application and test the UI of each Fragment. I can test the first Fragment and get all Views of this, but when I click on a Button or something else (to replace the Fragment with another Fragment) I can't get any View of the new Fragment, but my MainActivity says that the current Fragment is the new Fragment.

```
@UiThreadTest
public void testNewFragmentScrollView() {
    assertTrue(mActivity.getFragmentType().equals(FragmentTypes.FRAGMENT_STARTSCREEN));
    ivNewFragment.performClick(); // replace fragment
    sleep();
    assertTrue(mActivity.getFragmentType().equals(FragmentTypes.FRAGMENT_NEW));
    //get something from new fragment, ID is copied from xml file and not false
    ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.sv_fragment_new_scrollable);    
    assertTrue(scrollView != null); //#false???
    mActivity.finish();
}
```

Do I have to update something in my Testclass or why i'm getting no Views from the new Fragment?

Comment: I set a breakpoint at NewFragment.onCreateView() and I come into it after test method is called. It seems that the view is build too late and because of that I can't get any view element of it. I tried to increase the sleep method upon 5 seconds but problem still exists. So does somebody have an idea how I can update the view of the fragment before I get any content of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I solved my problem by splitting the code. When I change the Fragment in setUp and wait some ms, I can get all views from the new Fragment in each testmethod

```
@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);
    mActivity = getActivity();
    buNewFragment =(Button) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.bu_actionbar_newfragment);
    mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            buNewFragment .performClick();
        }
    });
    sleep(500);//simple Thread.sleep() method
}

@UiThreadTest
public void testNewFragmentScrollView() {
    assertTrue(mActivity.getFragmentType().equals(FragmentTypes.FRAGMENT_NEW));
    ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.sv_fragment_new_scrollable);
    assertTrue(scrollView != null); //#t
}
```

Comment: Hi, does it have something to do with the setup method? I am trying to do a similar thing, I am opening the navigation drawer, clicking and item, waiting some miliseconds and then trying to read the views in my fragment but it doesn't seem to be working, I get `junit.framework.AssertionFailedError`...